# Pulling information from multiple servers with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query that will pull information from multiple servers. Let me explain a little bit. The machine that makes a certain product stores that information on a server. So when we do reports we have to run a query on the accounting side and then run a query on the first server. I  was just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction, or help me out a little with constructing this query.

Comment: I see from the tags that you're talking about joining/mashing data from MySQL and SQL Server.  The program (web page, script, exe) will have to do that work in memory.  Depending on the expected results from each database, the implementation will vary in order to keep performance up to snuff.  What is the technology you are using to render the report?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't technically specify, I'm assuming you're running the query in MS SQL Server and the other databases are either MSSQL or MySQL, guessing based on your tags.

If that's the case you have a couple options. If you're going to be running these queries frequently you can use a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) or if you're only wanting to do them sparingly you can use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

Other options would be to create a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package to extract the data from various sources and compile it into a single report or alternatively SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).